# How does one adjust ColorFunction quality independently of surface quality?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I have a function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ which I would like to visualize by by plotting $|f|$ with `Plot3D` using $\operatorname{Arg}f$ as the `ColorFunction`.

I use

```
DensityPlot[Arg[f[a + I b]], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 35,
            WorkingPrecision -> 50, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

and get the following:

[image: nice]

which looks pretty nice.  However then when I use

```
Plot3D[Abs[f[a + I b]], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 35, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
      ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}}][Arg[f[#1 + I #2]]] &), 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Mesh -> None]
```

I get

[image: awful]

The quality of $\operatorname{Arg}f$ was fine in the DensityPlot using the same quality parameters, but it's awful when I make it a `ColorFunction`.  I suppose this is because the surface mesh is made from $|f|$ in the `Plot3D` and not from $\operatorname{Arg}f$ as it was in the `DensityPlot`, and $|f|$ isn't changing very much around the important parts of $\operatorname{Arg}f$ which is why it looks so choppy and noticable.

So, how do I fix this?  Is there a way to give the `ColorFunction` more `PlotPoints` than the actual surface, or perhaps a different mesh?  If possible I want to avoid just increasing `PlotPoints` for the overall plot, as I am happy with the quality of $|f|$ here, and it can be very slow to render as it is.

Comment: You don't give f. Is it intentional ?

Comment: Well, here `f[z_] := BesselI[0, 2 Sqrt[z]]/(1 - z)`, but I plan to do this with a lot of functions so I am really interested in a general method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is indeed an alternative which you might should consider. You almost got it yourself by the given analysis of the situation in your question. While `Plot3D` does only care of a good resolution of the function you plot and not the function you use for coloring, `DensityPlot` uses your color function from the beginning and tries to resolve this as best as possible.

Therefore, one possible way is to use the `DensityPlot` image as texture on your surface.

```
f[z_] := BesselI[0, 2 Sqrt[z]]/(1 - z)
img =
 Rasterize[
  DensityPlot[Arg[f[a + I b]], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, 
   PlotPoints -> 30, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", {-Pi, Pi}}][#] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Frame -> False, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0], "Image", 
  RasterSize -> 512];

Plot3D[Abs[f[a + I b]], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[img], Mesh -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Similar to halirutans answer you can let `DensityPlot` determine the "good points", and then `ListPlot3D` those:

```
ptsdp = Reap[
    DensityPlot[Arg[f[a + I b]], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, 
     PlotPoints -> 25, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{a, b}]]][[-1, 1]];
ListPlot3D[({#[[1]], #[[2]], Abs@f[Complex @@ #]}) & /@ ptsdp,
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}}][Arg[f[#1 + I #2]]] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

This generally has the drawback that the 3D sample points wont get refined further when need be. One possibility would be to `Join` the points with the ones `Plot3D` picks.

I was going to use [this trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/specific-initial-sample-points-for-3d-plots) but couldn't figure out the syntax for `Plot3D`

Comment: Needs more votes! The fact that you don't have to `Rasterize` and `Texture` is, IMO, a major advantage of this approach.

Answer (score 7):

You can add Arg[f] explicitly in the function to plot with ridiculously small coefficient. Then Mathematica will render points as you wish. Also it is good idea to put ExclusionStyle->Automatic to get rid of white lines. Below is your code with these corrections:

```
Block[{f = BesselI[0, 2 Sqrt[#]]/(1 - #) &},
  Plot3D[Abs[f[a + I b]] + 10^-50 Arg[f[a + I b]] // Evaluate, {a, -5, 
  5}, {b, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 35, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}}][
  Arg[f[#1 + I #2]]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False,  
  Mesh -> None, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic]
]
```

I also added Evaluate command, then result is plotted slightly faster. No need to increase WorkingPrecision or set up Performance goal. The output is:

[image]

There is a little flaw behind the peak, at the cross of blue and red regions. It is cured by increasing the number of PlotPoints, the cost is time of plotting.

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty smart trick. :) +1