# Plotting equipotentials gone wrong

Tags: plotting, homework

I'm plotting the equipotential of the potential function:
$$\phi(x,y,z):=\frac{1+x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}{[\left(1+x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{2}-4z^{2}]^{1/2}}$$
Mathematica code:

```
Φ[x_, y_, z_] := (1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/((1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 - 4 z^2)^(1/2)
```

So I write, for example

```
ContourPlot3D[Φ[x, y, z] == 1, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {z, -100, 100}]
```

But, I get this image:
[image]

And, sometimes if I change the plot region, I get absolutely nothing.

My **question** is, what did I wrong? I think I should obtain smooth 3D curves, but I don't.

Comment: The problem is that $\Phi(x,y,z)\ge1$ everywhere...

Comment: I think you should manipulate it mathematically a bit further.

Comment: Try `p[x_, z_] := (x x + z^2)/((x x + z^2)^2 - 4 z^2)^(1/2)
a = 5;
Plot3D[p[x, z], {x, 1, a}, {z, -a, a}]`

Comment: Or `a = 2;
ContourPlot3D[{\[CapitalPhi][x, y, z] == 
   1 + 1/100, \[CapitalPhi][x, y, z] == 1 + 1/10}, {x, -a, a}, {y, -a,
   a}, {z, -a, a}]`

Comment: As Rahul already pointed out, your contour is never *crossed*, only *touched*. `ContourPlot3D` fails with such things which I already answered [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23365/187). For a quick solution you should follow belisarius' last comment.

Comment: @belisarius maybe you could try to make a quick answer? :)