# Cissoid of Diocles not smooth plotted by ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

```
Table[ContourPlot[y^2 (10-x)==x^3,{x,0,.1},{y,-.1,.1},PlotPoints->5],{k,1,150,10}]
```

[image]

How to get the smooth graph?

When `PlotPoints` is larger than 500, performance is too slow, however still not good.

[image]

[image]

Comment: increase your plot points? btw. for what do you need k?

Comment: @Stefan `PlotPoints -> 500` two slow, however still not good ---! `x=0, y should be 0`.

Comment: i've used 50. still too slow?

Comment: @Stefan but when using `PlotPoints->50` output is not the right graph. Performance too slow.

Comment: Try an odd number of `PlotPoints`. You might also try `MaxRecursion->6` or so. Also, I wouldn't generally expect `ContourPlot`, which samples points on a 2D grid, to perform as well as `Plot`, which samples points on a 1D grid.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Good to learn that, it works pretty well. Thanks, you can post that as one answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, I would not generally expect `ContourPlot`, which samples points on a 2D grid, to perform as well as `Plot`, which samples points on a 1D grid.  That said, you can improve the plot by ensuring that you sample the function at the origin by simply using an odd number of `PlotPoints`:

```
ContourPlot[y^2 (10 - x) == x^3, {x, 0, .1}, {y, -.1, .1},
  PlotPoints -> 25, MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image]

To make it clear what's going on here, let's zoom into your image and show the sample points.

```
{pic, {pts}} = Reap[ContourPlot[
  y^2 (10 - x) == x^3, {x, 0, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50,EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}], 
  ContourStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]];
Show[{pic, Graphics[{Point[pts], PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{0, 0}]}]},
  PlotRange -> -0.05]
```

[image]

The origin is the large red dot and it is simply missed.  Now, here's the same picture with `PlotPoints` set to 25 and `MaxRecursion` left at it's default value of 2.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but what's a 1D grid?

Comment: @cormullion Is grid not an $n$-dimensional concept for arbitrary, positive, integer $n$?  As in `GridGraph[{5}]` or `Grid[{{1,2,3,4,5}}]`.

Answer (score 7):

`ContourPlot` generally works on the principle of the [Intermediate Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), and works best when it can find points for which the function being plotted lies on either side of the contour level (which is hard, for example, for [equations of the form `f^2 == 0`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23363/problem-with-contourplot/23367#23367)).  For convenience I will talk about contours of the form `f == 0` and speak about the function changing sign instead of taking values above and below the contour level.

`ContourPlot` uses `PlotPoints` to divide the domain initially into rectangular cells.  `ContourPlot` decides which cells contain part of the contour and which contain connected components; in the adaptive refinement step (up to `MaxRecursion` steps), it also decides which might contain more of the contour, and which are not worth pursuing.  In a symmetric graph on a symmetric domain, whether there are an even or an odd number of `PlotPoint` can make a remarkable difference.  So can offsetting the domain to make it slightly asymmetrical.

---

It might be surprising that one can produce an excellent graph with just `PlotPoints -> 2`:

```
ContourPlot[y^2 (10 - x) == x^3, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, -0.1, 0.1}, 
    PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> #] & /@ {2, 4} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Good plots with PlotPoints->2]

This works for an even number of `PlotPoints` up to 14 and then fails for 16 or higher, as in the OP.  I will return to this later.  First I wish illustrate another point made above. The connectedness of the contour seems (naturally) related to the values of the function on the sample grid.  If a function does not change sign, then the cell contains a disconnected segment of the contour or no segment.  This can change as sample points are added under adaptive refinement.  This can be illustrated by manually adding extra sample points (as discussed in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/specific-initial-sample-points-for-3d-plots).  Here is the OP's 50-point plot and the same plot with an extra sample point added to each cell straddling the `x`-axis:

```
ContourPlot[y^2 (10 - x) == x^3, {x, 0, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, 
    PlotPoints -> {{50}, #}, MaxRecursion -> 0, ImageSize -> 150, 
    BaseStyle -> Tiny, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.04}, Automatic}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{Length@#, " extra points"}]] & /@
  {{}, Table[{x0, 0}, {x0, 0.05/49, 0.1, 0.1/49}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: 50 PlotPoints, w & w/o extra sample points]

Adaptive refinement slowly connects the components generated by the extra sample points to the curve (`MaxRecursion` is set to `2`, `4`, `6`):

```
Table[ContourPlot[y^2 (10 - x) == x^3, {x, 0, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, 
   PlotPoints -> {{50}, Table[{x0, 0}, {x0, 0.05/49, 0.1, 0.1/49}]}, 
   MaxRecursion -> mr, PlotLabel -> mr, ImageSize -> 150, 
   BaseStyle -> Tiny, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.04}, Automatic}],
 {mr, 2, 6, 2}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Adaptive refinement of extra sample points]

I will try to explain what is happening below.

---

For an even number of `PlotPoints` up to `14`, a very large proportion of the plot domain is empty (all `x` less than `0.08` or rectangle at least 80% of the area).  There must be some threshold that triggers `ContourPlot` to subdivide the whole domain.  In cases of 2, 4,..., 14 points, the first subdivision effectively adds the points corresponding to `PlotPoints` being set to 3, 5,..., 15 points resp.  In the OP's case, a low number of plot points happens to work well because of the symmetry of the plot.

**The case of `PlotPoints -> 16`**

The function `adaptivePlotGrid[plotpoints, xMax, maxRecursion]` is a tool for exploring the adaptive refinement procedure (code below).  It shows the orginal sample grid (thin brown lines), the new sample points (red) and the previously generated sample points (light gray) for a succession of refinements.

Here we can see the adaptive refinement working its way back to the origin for `PlotPoints -> 16`.  When an original cell is subdivided at `y == 0`, the (approximate) contour in that cell is incorporated into the contour plot.  We can see that the origin is first incorporated into the plot at step `MaxRecursion -> 13`; subsequent refinements result in better approximations to the contour.

```
adaptivePlotGrid[16, 0.09, 15]
```

[image: <code>PlotPoints -> 16</code>]

**The case of `PlotPoints -> 50`**

The OP's case is similar to the case of `PlotPoints -> 50`, but it has many more cells to work through to get back to the origin.  The origin is still not reached when the limit of `MaxRecursion -> 15` is reached.

Aside:  An issue with adding extra sample points is discussed in the [linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/specific-initial-sample-points-for-3d-plots).  The cells with an extra sample point in them (apparently) will not be subdivided until an adjacent cell is subdivided and the shared side is split.  When this happens, the components of the contour on the adjacent cells are joined (assuming the changes in sign of the function at the sample points indicate they join, as in the OP's case).

**The case of `PlotPoints -> 2`**

The case of `PlotPoints -> 2` may interesting, too.  Here we see the initial graph is blank.  The first refinement adds the origin (as other points, on and off the `x`-axis, not shown due to the `PlotRange`). Then the adaptive refinement is on its way to plotting a more and more accurate contour.

```
adaptivePlotGrid[2, 0.04, 3]
```

[image: PlotPoints ->2]

---

```
adaptivePlotGrid[pp_, maxX_: 0.04, maxMR_: 5] := 
 Module[{pts, mr1 = 0, mr2 = maxMR, dmr = 1},
  pts[mr1 - dmr] = {};
  Partition[
    Table[
     {pic, {pts[mr]}} = 
      Reap[ContourPlot[y^2 (10 - x) == x^3, {x, 0, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, 
        PlotPoints -> pp, MaxRecursion -> mr, 
        EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}], PlotLabel -> mr, 
        PlotRange -> {{-0.002, maxX}, {-0.015, 0.015}}, 
        ImageSize -> 150, BaseStyle -> Tiny]];
     Show[{Graphics[{LightBrown, 
         Line[Table[{{x0, -0.1}, {x0, 0.1}}, {x0, 0., 0.1, 0.1/(pp - 1)}]], 
         Line[Table[{{0., y0}, {0.1, y0}}, {y0, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2/(pp - 1)}]],
         PointSize[Tiny], LightGray, Point[pts[mr - dmr]],
         Red, Point[Complement[pts[mr], pts[mr - dmr]]]}],
       pic, 
       Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny],
         Red, Point[Cases[Complement[pts[mr], pts[mr - dmr]], {_, 0.}]]}]},
       Options[pic]],
     {mr, mr1, mr2, dmr}],
    4, 4, 1, {}] // GraphicsGrid
  ]
```

Comment: Note: There seems to be a bug in V10 using `PlotLabel` with `BaseStyle -> Tiny`.  (Reported to WRI.)

Answer (score 7):

I knew about `MaxBend` for `Plot` and `ParametricPlot`, but I've never thought of applying it to `ContourPlot` until I saw [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31164/resolution-problem-of-contourplot/31169#31169) today by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard).

Setting `MaxBend` to a very low value will force `ContourPlot` to refine the curve as many times as allowed by `MaxRecursion`.

```
ContourPlot[y^2 (10 - x) == x^3, {x, 0, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, 
 Method -> {MaxBend -> 0.01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is already an improvement over the default plot.  Increase `MaxRecursion` from 2 to 3 and the plot is quite good.

```
ContourPlot[y^2 (10 - x) == x^3, {x, 0, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, 
 Method -> {MaxBend -> 0.01}, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

The advice about using an appropriate number (odd, in this case) for `PlotPoints`, which has been pointed out by [Mark McClure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36/mark-mcclure), is excellent.  But perhaps it is worth pointing out that `MaxBend` can overcome the deficiency inherent in a small, even number of `PlotPoints`:

```
ContourPlot[y^2 (10 - x) == x^3, {x, 0, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, 
 Method -> {MaxBend -> 0.01}, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Yet another method in V10, `"BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"` in the FEM mesh generation functionality.  It's quite simple if one is satisfied with a `RegionPlot` instead of a `ContourPlot`.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

mesh = ToElementMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[y^2 (10 - x) <= x^3, {{x, 0, 1/10}, {y, -1/10, 1/10}}],
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"];
RegionPlot[mesh]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or the curve can be extracted from the mesh elements and the spurious boundary at the edge of the plot range can be deleted.

```
Show[
 DeleteCases[
  Normal@ mesh["Wireframe"[
     "MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements",
     "MeshElementStyle" -> 
      Directive[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
       AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]]]], 
  Line[{{x1_ /; Abs[x1 - 0.1] < 10^-8, _Real},
        {x2_ /; Abs[x2 - 0.1] < 10^-8, _Real}}],
  Infinity
  ],
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1/10}, {-1/10, 1/10}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]