# Resolution problem of ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I met a tricky problem with `ContourPlot`, which is when I change the range of my variable, I get a totally new figure. For example:

```
ContourPlot[2.` c^4 - 1.693 c^4 x - 0.861 x^2 + 0.0417 Log[10^(-6)] x^2 + 
   0.25` x^2 Log[1/c^(2/3)] + (1.` c^4 + 0.673 x) x Log[x] - 
   0.125` x^2 Log[x]^2 == 0, {x, 3, 100}, {c, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

But if I change the range of `c` from `{1,5}` to `{1,50}` the figure is different:

[image]

Anyone knows the reason? Which figure is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a resolution problem. It can be cured by increasing the number of `PlotPoints` used:

```
Table[ContourPlot[
  2.` c^4 - 1.6931471805599454` c^4 x - 0.8611473146305157` x^2 + 
    0.041666666666666664` Log[10^(-6)] x^2 + 
    0.25` x^2 Log[
      1/c^(2/3)] + (1.` c^4 + 0.6732867951399863` x) x Log[x] - 
    0.125` x^2 Log[x]^2 == 0, {x, 3, 100}, {c, 1, 50}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> pp, 
  PlotLabel -> "PlotPoints \[Rule] " <> ToString[pp] ],
 {pp, {Automatic, 150}}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

rcollyer is right about the source of the problem, but there are better (faster) ways to handle it than merely cranking up the [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotPoints.html).  With that option alone I needed about `PlotPoints -> 300` to get a smooth line, which took seven seconds to render:

```
eq = 2.` c^4 - 1.6931471805599454` c^4 x - 0.8611473146305157` x^2 + 
    0.041666666666666664` Log[10^(-6)] x^2 + 
    0.25` x^2 Log[1/c^(2/3)] + (1.` c^4 + 0.6732867951399863` x) x Log[x] - 
    0.125` x^2 Log[x]^2 == 0;

ContourPlot[Evaluate @ eq, {x, 3, 100}, {c, 1, 50},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 300] //AbsoluteTiming //Column
```

[image]

[`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxRecursion.html) helps a lot in this case:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate @ eq, {x, 3, 100}, {c, 1, 50},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotPoints -> 75,
  MaxRecursion -> 6
] // AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

[image]

Even better here appears to be controlling the lower level [`MaxBend`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8484/121) parameter:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate @ eq, {x, 3, 100}, {c, 1, 50},
  PlotRange -> All,
  MaxRecursion -> 3,
  Method -> {MaxBend -> 0.5}
] // AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

[image]

Comment: I've always pushed the number of `PlotPoints` as even with the slow-down, it seems to do the trick. Also, I tend to be leery of `MaxRecursion` as I've used it to shut-down my machine before. `MaxBend`, however, looks promising.

Comment: @rcollyer You're right, you do have to be careful of `MaxRecursion` as it can run away rather easily.