# Mathematica Contour Plot Problem

Tags: plotting

When I type

```
ContourPlot[x == Sin[6*Pi*y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

I get this

[image: Penis]

Now I'm not a particularly gifted mathematician, but I have a feeling this just might be wrong. How do I get Mathematica to plot it correctly?

Comment: closely related: [31164](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31164/5478)

Comment: I'm gathering you're new to Mathematica.  Is this plot truly what you were seeking?  You're plotting a logical (Boolean) function--i.e., one that has output *TRUE* or *FALSE*.  I suspect you wanted to plot $Sin[6 \pi y]$ or something like that.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, I wanted to plot $x = Sin [6 \pi y]$, this should have worked in theory though

Comment: @LTS A *much* better way is $Plot[Sin[6 \pi y], \{y, -2,2\}]$...  You don't have to specify the range of the output; it generalizes to other functions immediately; it is understood by others better, and on and on.  Another question to you:  Do you really want to be the $.00001\%$ of cases where you plot $x$ as a function of $y$, instead of the standard $y$ versus $x$ used in every textbook and technical presentation?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No, I want to plot the inverse of $\sin[6\pi x]$. I could write it as an explicit function of x, but that would be rather difficult since it's not a proper function.

Comment: @LTS:  If you want to plot the inverse, just use `ArcSin[]`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork But ArcSin has a restricted range in order to make it a valid function. I want the whole thing

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Also if the function were more complicated I may not wish to go through the trouble of inverting it, if the function is even invertible, which this isn't.

Comment: @Kuba I closed the question as a duplicate of the one you linked.  If you (or anyone else) disagrees with this action please notify me with `@Mr.Wizard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContourPlot is not as smart as you so you have to give it more `PlotPoints` to sample domain or use more suited for this job function:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[6*Pi*y], y}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about ParametricPlot.

Answer (score 1):

```
ContourPlot[x == Sin[6*Pi*y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just increase `MaxRecursion` to track the curve correctly

```
ContourPlot[x == Sin[6*Pi*y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

Usually `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` options solve almost all resolution problems.