# Resolution Problem of Contour Plot (Local)

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

I have a smooth function which near one point has a very rapid change, a peak with a very very narrow width!

[image]

That if I plot the blank region with a function like r= -18.5+20.6 Tanh(u) at r->2

[image]

I want to actually, increase the resolution of the first ContourPlot maybe just locally (as r->2) so I can have the whole graph in one plot and show the behavior of my function in one clean plot.
So far I tried increasing the PlotPoints, using MaxRecursion and everything that is explained here: [Resolution problem of ContourPlot Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31164/resolution-problem-of-contourplot), and yet no luck! Any idea please?

Comment: `PlotPoints->`00`?

Comment: `PlotPontis->00`? I never heard of, you mean instead of 100 I should go with 00? I just tried it and it says "Value of option PlotPoints -> 0 is not an integer >= 2"

Comment: Try adding Exclusions->None

Comment: @CarlWoll you are a life saver, thanks! it worked perfectly

Comment: Typo above:  `PlotPoints->100`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yeah, that was the first thing I tried actually and didn't help much, but `Exclusions->None` solved my problem. Still, I added MaxRecursion.