# Enigmatic message about MaxBend

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, undocumented

Referring to the method I proposed for [Problem with ParametricPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8482/problem-with-parametricplot/8484#8484) *Mathematica* 10.0.2 throws an enigmatic error message:

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 5}, Method -> {MaxBend -> 1}]
```

> MaxBend::deprec: MaxBend->1 is deprecated and will not be supported in future versions of the Wolfram Language. Use Method->{MaxBend->1} instead.

I don't know if this message is entirely a mistake or if it is really trying to tell me that there is a different form I should be using now.  Is this same message generated by 10.1.0?  Is there a known different form for `MaxBend`?

Comment: It's probably not a bug, but a bug

Comment: I see it in 10.1 on Win8.1.

Comment: Does it possibly mean `"MaxBend"` as a string? (Obviously it will not give the message if so, so you will have to verify that it really has the intended effect. A string does not work in 9.0.1.)

Comment: @Oleksandr Good idea!  However `Method -> {"MaxBend" -> 1}` throws the same error. :-/

Comment: Does the alternative `Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (* radian angle *) }}` still work, tho?

Comment: @J. M. Yes, and without an error message.  However `MaxBend` *also* works so I am just turning `Off` the message.

Comment: Personally, I've always assumed it's a typo, that `MaxBend` is in fact deprecated, and the message was supposed to point the user to `Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (*radian angle*) }}`.  I was hoping someone from WRI would comment on your question, though, to clarify. Have you reported it to WRI?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nuts.  I misremembered *and* misread my own comment above; I thought that form *also* gave an error, but since it does not I think your explanation is certainly plausible if not more.  I shall remove the `bugs` tag now.  *edit: No, I did not report this to WRI.  There are  many more important things that need work so I feel it would be counterproductive.*

Comment: @Karsten That form does not appear to work.  It throws no errors but it also doesn't have any effect.

Comment: It still works without any message for `ContourPlot` as used [in this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/70008/18476).

Comment: @Karsten Confirmed.  Thanks.

Comment: Certainly reporting it is not a priority -- I haven't done it either, and I've been aware of the message for some time.  Just wondering, I guess, considering `MaxBend` has apparently been deprecated or at least missing from the docs since V6.

Comment: A similar, useless message can be generated with the option `Method -> {PlotDivision -> 2}`.

Comment: Autocompletion even suggest `MaxBend` as a `Method` [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9T0JT.png).

Answer (score 2):

*Earlier invalid assertion redacted.*

Some spelunking reveals that the innermost (accessible) plot function called is:

```
Visualization`Core`Plot
```

And using this function directly also produces the message:

```
Visualization`Core`Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, Method -> {"MaxBend" -> 1}]
```

> MaxBend::deprec: MaxBend->7 is deprecated and will not be supported in future versions of the Wolfram Language. Use Method->{MaxBend->7} instead.

I have failed in my attempts to trace the origin of the problem further but I may try again later.

Comment: Note that `tr2 = With[{gr = 1/GoldenRatio}, Trace[{AspectRatio -> gr, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Method -> {"MaxBend" -> 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-0.21723357397428536`, 0.999999999999993`}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02`], Scaled[0.02`]}}]];  tr2 === Query[35, 1][tr]` returns `True`.  How do you deduce that `"MaxBend"` is being duplicated?  It seems to me that the multiple instances could be the result of the evaluation chain. I note that some things are not evaluated to very bottom of the expression tree, so I might be wrong.  Definitely confused.

Comment: @MichaelE2 *Facepalm* -- no, I think you're quite right and I'm crazy.  Trying too hard!