# Problem with code from Stan Wagon's book

Tags: plotting

Stan Wagon's Third Edition of *Mathematica in Action* has this code on page 30:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi},
    Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (90 - n °)}},
    Mesh -> All,
    MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]},
    PlotPoints -> 8],
  {n, 0, 90, 2}]
```

It does not work. Are `Refinement` and `ControlValue` options of the past for *Mathematica*?

Is there a workaround for this code?

**The Cure**

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi},
  Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (90 - n) \[Degree]}},
  Mesh -> All,
  MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]},
  PlotPoints -> 8],
 {n, 0, 90, 2}
 ]
```

Folks are correct, the degree symbol was misplaced. However, my real question here is why do `Refinement` and `ControlValue` have blue rather than black coloring in my notebook, and why can I not find them in the documentation?

Comment: Have you tried the Extras [Mathematica® in Action](http://extras.springer.com/2010/978-0-387-75366-9)?

Comment: [Where I can find the CD version of Stan Wagon - “Mathematica in action” 3rd ed. book?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87284/where-i-can-find-the-cd-version-of-stan-wagon-mathematica-in-action-3rd-ed)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(8484)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8484/121), [(29348)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29348/121) Also see [(79980)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79980/121)

Comment: (90 -n Degree) looks suspicious. The first part is quite probably supposed to be an angle in degrees (but it isn't now), the second part is in radians. My guess is that it should be (90-n)Degree.

Answer (score 4):

David, replace

```
Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (90 - n °)}}
```

with

```
Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (90 - n) °}}`
```

Comment: More detail would be helpful

Comment: @bbgodfrey Misplaced parenthesis in OP's code. See my comment above.

Comment: @Willinski . Yes, that is definitely a mistake, but my real question here is why do Refinement and ControlValue remain in blue, and why can I not find them in the documentation?

Comment: @David, `MaxBend` used to be documented, but stopped being documented since version 6 IIRC.