# ContourPlot shows only part of the contours

Tags: plotting

Consider these contour plots:

```
f[x_,y_]:=Cos[x] + Cos[y]

ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y]*f[x, y] == 0, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Abs[f[x, y]] == 0, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image]

**Question**: Why the second and third contour plot don't work? How to fix them to make them to reproduce the first contour plot?

I tried to increase the `MaxRecursion` and it's supper slow and doesn't help much:

```
ContourPlot[Abs[f[x, y]] == 0, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 15]
```

[image]

---

---

This part is just my context of the problem, you can safely ignore it if you are not interested.

Why do I want to plot the contour of `Abs[f[x,y]]==0` or `f[x,y]*Conjugate[f[x,y]]==0` if they are the same of `f[x,y]==0`?

Because it would help a lot when `f[x,y]` is a complex function(x and y are real variables but `f[x,y]` maybe complex). For any function `f[x,y]`, it can be written in the form `r[x,y]*Exp[I θ[x,y]]` where `r[x,y]` and `θ[x,y]` are real function. So for `f[x,y]==0` what we really means is `r[x,y]==0`, and instead of contour plotting `f[x,y]==0` I should put `r[x,y]==0`. However, sometimes it would be difficult to get `r[x,y]` given the function `f[x,y]`, but fortunately we can just plot the contour of `f[x,y]*Conjugate[f[x,y]]==0` or `Abs[f[x,y]]==0` since which is mathematically equivalent to `r[x,y]==0`.

For example,

I have a function

```
a0 = 10.;a = 1.4;
f[k_,K0_]:=a^2 Sech[(a a0)/2]^2 (-2 I (1 + E^(2 I a0 k)) k + a (-1 + E^(2 I a0 k)) Tanh[(a a0)/2]) + 2 k (I E^(I a0 k) ((a - k) (a + k) Cos[a0 k] + (a^2 + k^2) Cos[a0 K0]) + a (-1 + E^(2 I a0 k)) k Tanh[(a a0)/2])
```

I know it can be separate into the form `r[k,K0]*Exp[I θ[k,K0]]`, but it's difficult to find what `r` and `θ` is. Since I want to plot the contour of `r[k,K0]==0`, instead I can plot the contour of  `Abs[f[k,K0]]==0`, but I encountered the same problem as the simple example above.

```
ContourPlot[Abs[f[k, K0]] == 0, {K0, -2 π/a0, 2 π/a0}, {k, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

However if we plot the real and imaginary part, we can get the correct contour(the diamond shape) but also introduced other artificial contours(horizontal lines) come from `Cos[θ[x,y]]==0` or `Sin[θ[x,y]]==0`.

```
Row@{ContourPlot[
   Re[f[k, K0]] == 0, {K0, -2 π/a0, 2 π/a0}, {k, 0, 4}, PlotLabel -> "Re", PlotPoints -> 60],
  ContourPlot[
   Im[f[k, K0]] == 0, {K0, -2 π/a0, 2 π/a0}, {k, 0, 4}, PlotLabel -> "Im", PlotPoints -> 60]}
```

[image]

Just for comparison, the above function can be separated into

```
2 I E^(I a0 k) (a^2 Sech[(a a0)/2]^2 (-2 k Cos[a0 k] + a Sin[a0 k] Tanh[(a a0)/2]) + k ((a - k) (a + k) Cos[a0 k] + (a^2 + k^2) Cos[a0 K0] + 2 a k Sin[a0 k] Tanh[(a a0)/2]))
```

so

```
r[k_,K0_]:=a^2 Sech[(a a0)/2]^2 (-2 k Cos[a0 k] + a Sin[a0 k] Tanh[(a a0)/2]) + 
 k ((a - k) (a + k) Cos[a0 k] + (a^2 + k^2) Cos[a0 K0] + 
    2 a k Sin[a0 k] Tanh[(a a0)/2])
```

and contour plot of r is

```
ContourPlot[r[k, K0] == 0, {K0, -2 \[Pi]/a0, 2 \[Pi]/a0}, {k, 0, 4}, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Problem with ContourPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23363/484).

Comment: @RahulNarain You're right, thanks for finding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the difficulties that `ContourPlot` is having can be attributed to the fact that you are looking for a contour right at the boundary of the function's range, i.e., $0$ for a function whose range is $f(x,y)\ge 0$. Since there is no loss of visual accuracy in moving this contour slightly into the allowed range of values, I would do it this way:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y]*f[x, y] == 0.000001, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: contours]

and similarly for the other examples.

**Edit**

Unfortunately, this still doesn't work when the **maximal** function values vary steeply across the plot region, as is the case in the example

```
a0 = 10.; a = 1.4;
f[k_, K0_] := 
 a^2 Sech[(a a0)/2]^2 (-2 I (1 + E^(2 I a0 k)) k + 
     a (-1 + E^(2 I a0 k)) Tanh[(a a0)/2]) + 
  2 k (I E^(I a0 k) ((a - k) (a + k) Cos[a0 k] + (a^2 + k^2) Cos[
          a0 K0]) + a (-1 + E^(2 I a0 k)) k Tanh[(a a0)/2])
```

if we plot the `Abs`. Then the absolute contour value of, say, `0.01` is perhaps OK in part of the plot where the function itself varies only between `0` and `1`, but it won't be large enough relative to the typical function values in regions where the maxima reach values of `100` or more.

In this case one could try to replace the constant contour value (`0.01`) by something that varies in the direction in which the range increases most rapidly. However, I don't have any good way of doing this in an automated way, so it would require manual tuning.

So here is a manual approach where I slice the contour plot into 9 different regions where the contours can then be identified in a hopefully more accurate way because the function doesn't vary too rapidly in each slice:

```
c = {{0, .01}, {.5, .03}, {1, .05}, {1.5, .15}, {2, .2}, \
{2.5, .5}, {3, 1}, {3.5, 1}, {4, 10}}

(*
==> {{0, 0.01}, {0.5, 0.03}, {1, 0.05}, {1.5, 0.15}, {2, 
  0.2}, {2.5, 0.5}, {3, 1}, {3.5, 1}, {4, 10}}
*)

t = Table[
  ContourPlot[
   Abs[f[k, K0]] == c[[i, 2]], {K0, -2 Pi/a0, 2 Pi/a0}, {k, 
    c[[i, 1]], c[[i + 1, 1]]}, PlotPoints -> 100],
  {i, 1, Length[c] - 1}];

Show[t, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: slices]

Comment: Thanks, but for the other example, I can't make it work by setting a small value instead of zero, could you have a look?

Comment: @xslittlegrass Are you sure? The `Abs[]`example works here by using the same trick

Comment: @Jens I guess yes, here is a screen shot http://i.imgur.com/8eBA2ju.png?1

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it seems there is something else other than the steeply change of the function maximals. For example, consider this `f[x_, y_] := (Cos[x] + Cos[y]) Exp[I x y] Exp[x/2]
Plot3D[Abs[f[x, y]] == 0.001, {x, 0, 8 Pi}, {y, 0, 8 Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 40, PlotRange -> All]
ContourPlot[Abs[f[x, y]] == 0.00001, {x, 0, 8 Pi}, {y, 0, 8 Pi}]`. The function maximals change quit a lot in the region, but `ContourPlot` still works quit well. Do you have any idea why it works?

Comment: I'm thinking that if the bad behave part is the steeply change of the maximals, we may re-scale the function in the second example to make the maximals well behave, and than use the the same trick `f[x, y]*f[x, y] == 0.000001` as you did in the first example.

Comment: @Jens I investigated some of the above behavior in more detail and found it very confusing. Could you have a look? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/why-contourplot-behaves-like-this

Comment: I do not agree with the explanation "the difficulties that `ContourPlot` is having can be attributed to the fact that the boundary of the function's range". See [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32945/8803).