# Cannot get plot of polynomial (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4)^2 == 0 from ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, polynomials

I'm trying to make a 3D contour plot the polynomial equation

$$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4)^2 == 0, \quad \quad (1)$$

Without power 2

$$ (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4) == 0, \quad \quad (2)$$

it plots a sphere with radius 2. With power 2 $(1)$ it plots an empty set.

My motivation is to 3D contour plot the polynomial equation

$$ (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4)^2 + ((x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 1)^2 == 0, \quad \quad  (3) $$

But the result is the same as in $(1)$. (Plotting this solution set might be even more tricky as it is not a surface, but a 3D curve;)

These polynomials don't seem to be very complex (max. deg. 4) and with some modification (as with adding +x) it plots.

I'm looking forward to any idea to fix that and so I can produce  a 3D contour plot these polynomials.

Comment: Actually, no need to bring 3D plotting into it, the problem is still there in 2D.  Compare the output of `ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2 - 4)^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None]` to `ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2 - 4), {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> {0},  ContourShading -> None]`

Comment: One workaround would be to substitute a very small value for 0.  This will give the approximate curve for the 2D case:  `ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2 - 4)^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},  Contours -> {0.001}, ContourShading -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]`  A similar thing works for the 3D case

Comment: Look at the last example under Examples > Possible Issues in the Document Center article for [`ContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html). You will find an example similar to yours with the statement, "For functions that are always non-negative, it is not possible to find the 0 contour".

Comment: Closely related: [87805](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87799/one-mesh-line-does-not-show-up-in-contourplot/87805#87805)

Answer (score 3):

As m_goldberg pointed out, the [ContourPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) Help page says "For functions that are always non-negative, it is not possible to find the 0 contour".  So you have two options:  plot a very small contour, or solve the equation for one of the variables and plot the result as a function of the other two.

Here are both solutions for your original equation:

```
ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4)^2, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, 
  {z, -2.5, 2.5}, Contours -> {0.05}, PlotPoints -> 150]
soln = Solve[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4)^2 == 0, z];
Plot3D[z /. soln, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

The first method seems to be more robust.  Just adding in the `+((x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 1)^2` to the function gives the following output:

[image]