# A particular contour does not show up, even though it is in my list

Tags: plotting

Consider:

```
f = Sqrt[9 - x^2 - y^2];
ContourPlot[f, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
 Contours -> {0, 1, 2, 3},
 ContourLabels -> All,
 ContourShading -> None]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

Now, I understand that the contour f=3 is just the point (0,0) and maybe that's why it's not drawn. But I don't understand why the contour f=0, which should be a circle of radius 3, is missing?

Any thoughts?

Comment: For x=y=3,  f is complex

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero `9 - x^2 - y^2 /. {x -> 3/Sqrt@2, y -> 3/Sqrt@2}`

Comment: `Sqrt[9 - 3^2 - 3^2] = 3i`

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero: When finding the contour $f=0$, we're working with $\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}=0$, which is equivalent to $x^2+y^2=9$, which is a circle of radius 3. We are not substituting 3 for $x$ and $y$. But see Michael Seifert's answer. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(23363)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23363/problem-with-contourplot/23367#23367), [(32734)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/how-to-plot-the-contour-of-fx-y-0-if-always-fx-y-0/33268#33268)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Why not vote to close?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My plotting badge means my single vote would close it.  I would rather someone (or two) agree first.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry, I completely forgot about gold badge closes; I do the same thing.  I agree that this seems to be a duplicate of 23363; if that's good enough for you I suggest you go ahead and close it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be a problem with the square root:

```
f = 9 - x^2 - y^2;
ContourPlot[f, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> {0, 1, 4, 9}, 
 ContourLabels -> (Text[Sqrt[#3], {#1, #2}] &), ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

My guess is that the algorithm used by `ContourPlot` implicitly relies on the function having a smooth gradient in some neighborhood of each contour, which the function $f = \sqrt{9 - x^2 - y^2}$ does not have in the neighborhood of the level set $f = 0$.

Comment: Probably a good point. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

```
f = Sqrt[9 - x^2 - y^2];

Reduce[f == 0, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> -3 <= x <= 3 &&     (y == -Sqrt[9 - x^2] || 
>         y == Sqrt[9 - x^2])

Mathematica has a hard time finding a real solution for `f == 0`. Using a large number of `PlotPoints` and forcing the result to be real using `Re` produces a highly segmented plot (multiple labels for `0`)

```
ContourPlot[Re[f], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> {0, 1, 2, 3},
 ContourLabels -> All,
 ContourShading -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 201]
```

[image]

For a workaround use `RegionPlot`:

```
Row[{
  RegionPlot[
   ImplicitRegion[
      Reduce[
       Sqrt[9 - x^2 - y^2] == #, {x, y}, Reals],
      {x, y}] & /@
    Range[0, 3],
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}},
   ImageSize -> 360],
  LineLegend[
   {Red, Darker[Green], Orange, Blue},
   Range[3, 0, -1]]}]
```

[image]