# Plotting in for loop

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am having some problem while plotting the data being generated in for loop
My aim is to plot the result of for loop while it is solving the equation for each value of w,i.e. plot between w and x

Here is the minimum working example

```
For[w = 0.9925, w < 1.0075, w += 0.0015, 
    Plot[Solve[{x^6 + x^4 + w*x^2 == 0 , x > 0}, x, Reals], {w}]
]
```

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to plot there. But these are no solutions any way. If you do `For[w = 0.9925, w < 1.0075, w += 0.0015,
 Print[Solve[{x^6 + x^4 + w*x^2 == 0, x > 0}, x, Reals]]
 ]` then it gives no solution for all values.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I want to plot w vs x, where value of w are define by increment and x is the solution of the equation

Comment: `For` & `Do` loops have no output.  Perhaps `Table` is a better.  See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica -- I'll let the answer speak to how to use `Solve` and `Plot`.

Answer (score 3):

`ContourPlot` has a bug! It missing some curves , for example  the x=0 !

```
 ContourPlot[x^6 + x^4 + w*x^2 == 0, {w, -10, 10}, {x, -10, 10}, 
     PlotPoints -> 50, ContourStyle -> Red, FrameLabel -> {w, x}, 
     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 16, Blue}]
```

[image]

Or

```
 Clear["`*"];
Solve[x^6 + x^4 + w*x^2 == 0 , x, Method -> Reduce]
Plot[x /. % // Evaluate, {w, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> {w, x}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 12, Blue}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0125]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering but I need the value of x from the roots of above equation

Comment: "Bug" is a little strong.  See, for instance, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/how-to-plot-the-contour-of-fx-y-0-if-always-fx-y-0

Comment: Here's a hack: `ContourPlot[x^6 + x^4 + w*x^2 == $MachineEpsilon*w,...]`. Pretty much requires a symmetric `x` domain `{x, -a, a}`