# Plotting a line segment from the degenerate case of an ellipse

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometry

An ellipse degenerates into a line segment when the defining constant distance from the two foci is the actual distance between the two foci.  The ellipse closes into a line segment.

The following code shows a family of concentric ellipses that should converge to a line segment when the constant is set to 5.  However it doesn't plot the line segment even if I increase the MaxRecursion very high.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Table[Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + y^2] + Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 4)^2] == n, {n, 5, 
6, .01}]], {x, -4, 1}, {y, -1, 5}]
```

Is there someway to get Mathematica to actually plot the line segment of the degenerate case of an ellipse?

Comment: `Epilog -> Line[{{-3, 0}, {0, 4}}]` :)

Comment: @Kuba That does work to draw a line segment.  Thanks!  So I guess Mathematica just can't recognize the degenerate case of the ellipse and I'll have to use that method in place instead?

Comment: It's for the same reason as the problem in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23363/484).

Answer (score 1):

You can get an ellipse *almost* at the center, but you will need to increase the number of points in the plot:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Table[
   Sqrt[(x + 3)^2 + y^2] + Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 4)^2] == n, 
   {n, 5.0001, 6, .1}]], {x, -4, 1}, {y, -1, 5}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

It looks even more line-like if you decrease `n` to 5.00002 and increase PlotPoints to 600, though this dramatically increases the time required to draw the plot.