# RegionPlot not working as expected

Tags: plotting

I was trying to evaluate the following expression:

```
RegionPlot[a > 0 && 2 a + b == 0, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -1.5, 1},  
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

The output is:

[image]

I think this is unexpected. Think about when $a = 0.5$. So, $b = -1$ which is within the range $[-1.5, 1]$. So, this values and other such values should be in a gray region in the plot. But they are not there. Any help?

Comment: From `?RegionPlot`, *The predicate pred can be any logical combination of **inequalities**.* However, this won't work either: `RegionPlot[
 a > 0 && 2 a + b <= 0 && 2 a + b >= 0, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}]` I guess there must be a "true" region (with non null area), because *RegionPlot initially evaluates pred at a grid of equally spaced sample points specified by PlotPoints. Then it uses an adaptive algorithm to subdivide at most MaxRecursion times, attempting to find the boundaries of all regions in which pred is True.*

Comment: Jean-Claude is right. To create your plot you should make a `ContourPlot` of `2 a + b == 0` with `RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, a > 0]`.

Comment: @RahulNarain Are you going to answer or do you think it is a simple mistake? :)

Comment: This works. ContourPlot[2 a + b == 0, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -1.5, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, a > 0], 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]

Comment: @Kuba: Neither; I thought the question would be closed as a duplicate, but I was too lazy to check :) Turns out I was thinking of [a ContourPlot question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23363/484) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RegionPlot` can only plot filled regions, as explained in Jean-Claude's comment. Your equation defines a curve instead, so you should use `ContourPlot` and put the other inequality(s) inside its `RegionFunction`:

```
ContourPlot[2 a + b == 0, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -1.5, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, a > 0]]
```

[image]