# How can I mend this broken heart?

Tags: plotting, numerics

Try to evaluate the following code:

```
ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + 9/4 y^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 == x^2 z^3 + 9/80 y^2 z^3, 
  {x, -6/5, 6/5}, {y, -6/5, 6/5}, {z, -6/5, 3/2}, 
  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.58], Specularity[Yellow, 30]], 
  AspectRatio -> 1.15, ViewPoint ->{-0.930, -3.137, -0.860}]
```

The resulted heart looks broken:

[image]

Increase the `PlotPoints` value to up to `200` improves the appearance but does not solve it.

What is happening?

Comment: You have to orbit the picture to reproduce the problem

Comment: Does that mean you cannot reproduce the problem? which version you are using?

Comment: I can reproduce it with `PlotPoints` less than 250, I am using v9 at the moment. When I first ran the command I had to rotate/orbit the picture to the same angle as your screenshot to see the problem (artifacts along the x axis).

Comment: It appears that this is a problem only when z=0. try to plot ((x^2 + 9/4 y^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 == (x^2 z^3 + 9/80 y^2 z^3)) /. z -> 0 using ContourPlot to see what I mean

Comment: so its not a bug then?

Comment: @rm-rf *great* edit - just remember to go easy on the mushrooms :D

Comment: @YvesKlett To be fair, it's one of the best titles on this site! Made me smile :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Taking the cube root on both sides fixes the problem, and then you don't need lots of `PlotPoints` any more.

```
ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + 9/4 y^2 + z^2 - 1) == CubeRoot[x^2 z^3 + 9/80 y^2 z^3], 
{x, -6/5, 6/5}, {y, -6/5, 6/5}, {z, -6/5, 3/2}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Axes -> False, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.58], Specularity[Yellow, 30]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1.15, ViewPoint -> {-0.930, -3.137, -0.860}]
```

[image]

As Algohi pointed out, the problem only occurs at $z = 0$, at which the original equation becomes

```
(x^2 + 9/4 y^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 == x^2 z^3 + 9/80 y^2 z^3 /. z -> 0
```

> ```
> (-1 + x^2 + (9 y^2)/4)^3 == 0
> ```

Here every zero crossing is a critical point: the function doesn't cross zero briskly like most functions do, it lingers in the neighbourhood because its derivative is zero as well. Since the ContourPlot functions find the zero crossings numerically, they have a hard time getting the location exactly right. Take your favourite `ContourPlot` of any function $f(x,y)=0$ and try plotting $f(x,y)^3=0$ instead, and you'll see what happens. (Though if you plot $f(x,y)^2=0$ [you might not see anything at all](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23363/484).)

Comment: (+1) To make it work in version 8, I defined `CubeRoot[x_] := (Abs[x]^(1/3) Sign[x])`.

Comment: @RahulNarain +1, not only resolution of problem but explanation...very nice