# REAL Roots of a 2 variable Polynomial

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am looking to plot the real zeros of polynomials of two variables in Mathematica, but I have encountered an issue. To accomplish this task I have been using ContourPlot to plot the polynonial f(x,y)=0. For example see below: [image: Example Plot for a 2-variable polynomial]

Although I am getting the contour plot, there seems to be regions where the X and Y axis is "broken". I am considering polynomials which have form:`$\sum_{k=1}^3\sum_{l=1}^3 a_{k,l}x^ky^l$, thus the X and Y axis should always be real roots of the polynomial. Thus I think Mathematica is mixing up real and complex zeros possibly, and I was wondering if there is a way to remedy this issue as all I want are the real zero plots of these 2-variable polynomials.

Comment: To facilitate people assisting you, post copiable code blocks, not images of code.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why the contour is broken is because `ContourPlot` seems to be based on the Intermediate Value Theorem and it will fail to find points where the function just touches zero. The details have been discussed in the post [Problem with ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23363/1364).

For your question, you can first factor out `x` and `y`, then the contour will be fine:

```
P[x_, y_] := 
 0.226594 x y - 0.682774 x^2 y + 0.32404 x^3 y - 0.61382 x y^2 - 
  0.327897 x^2 y^2 + 0.124664 x^3 y^2 + 0.215339 x y^3 - 
  0.220948 x^2 y^3 + 0.698364 x^3 y^3

G[x_, y_] = P[x, y]/x/y // Simplify;

ContourPlot[G[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]