# How to make plot of implicit function?

Tags: plotting

I try to produce a plot of
$$\frac{1}{2}-\left| y\right| =\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left| y\right| \right)^2+(y-\sin (x))^2} $$
through

```
ContourPlot[1/2 - Abs[y] ==Sqrt[(1/2 - Abs[y])^2+(y-Sin[x])^2],
{x,-Pi,  Pi}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

, but I obtain an empty plot.

Comment: Isn't this solvable algebraically? You just get $y=\sin x$ such that $-\frac{1}{2}\le y\le\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: `ParametricPlot[If[1/2 - Abs[Sin[x]] > 0, {x, Sin[x]}, {}], {x, -Pi, Pi}]`

Comment: @Ian Miller: Please, peresent an algebraic solution to base your words.

Comment: @Coolwater: Please, base your code.

Comment: The result of `FullSimplify[Reduce[1/2 - Abs[y] == Sqrt[(1/2 - Abs[y])^2 + (y - Sin[x])^2], {x, y}, Reals], {x, y} ∈ Reals]` might be helpful in making a plot.

Comment: @J.M. : Thank you for your valuable comment. However, I still don't see how to programmatically draw the plot under consideration in view of the output of FullSimplify[ Reduce[1/2 - Abs[y] == Sqrt[(1/2 - Abs[y])^2 + (y - Sin[x])^2] &&   x >= -Pi && x <= Pi, {x, y}, Reals], {x, y} \[Element] Reals].

Comment: The underlying problem is that `ContourPlot` has a hard time plotting the contour of $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ [if the functions never cross each other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23363/484), i.e. you always have $f(x,y)\le g(x,y)$ and never $f(x,y)>g(x,y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[
  FullSimplify[
   Reduce[{1/2 - Abs[y] == 
      Sqrt[(1/2 - Abs[y])^2 + (y - Sin[x])^2], -Pi < x < Pi, -1 < y < 
      1}, {x, y}, Reals]], {x, y}]
RegionPlot[ir, 
 GridLines -> {{-Pi, -5 Pi/6, -Pi/6, Pi/6, 5 Pi/6, Pi}, None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved algebraically as follows:

$$\frac{1}{2}-\left| y\right| =\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left| y\right| \right)^2+(y-\sin (x))^2} $$

Firstly note that $\frac{1}{2}-|y|\ge0$ so $-\frac{1}{2}\le y\le\frac{1}{2}$.

Next square the equation:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left| y\right|\right)^2 =\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left| y\right| \right)^2+(y-\sin (x))^2 $$

$$0=(y-\sin(x))^2$$

$$0=y-\sin(x)$$

$$y=\sin(x)$$

So the solution is $y=\sin(x)$ such that $-\frac{1}{2}\le y\le\frac{1}{2}$.

Using Mathematica's `Solve` or `Reduce` gives the same result (it just gives restrictions on $x$ rather than $y$).

```
Solve[{1/2 - Abs[y] == Sqrt[(1/2 - Abs[y])^2 + (y - Sin[x])^2], Element[y, Reals], Element[x, Reals]}, y]

{{y -> ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], (C[1] \[Element] Integers && 2 \[Pi] C[1] <= x <= 1/6 (\[Pi] + 12 \[Pi] C[1])) || (C[1] \[Element] Integers && \[Pi] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] < x <= 1/6 (7 \[Pi] + 12 \[Pi] C[1])) || (C[1] \[Element] Integers && 1/6 (-\[Pi] + 12 \[Pi] C[1]) <= x < 2 \[Pi] C[1]) || (C[1] \[Element] Integers && 1/6 (5 \[Pi] + 12 \[Pi] C[1]) <= x <= \[Pi] + 2 \[Pi] C[1])]}}


Reduce[{1/2 - Abs[y] == Sqrt[(1/2 - Abs[y])^2 + (y - Sin[x])^2], Element[y, Reals], Element[x, Reals]}, y]

C[1] \[Element] Integers && (((2 \[Pi] C[1] <= x <= 1/6 (\[Pi] + 12 \[Pi] C[1]) || 1/6 (5 \[Pi] + 12 \[Pi] C[1]) <= x <= \[Pi] + 2 \[Pi] C[1]) && y == Sin[ x]) || ((1/6 (-\[Pi] + 12 \[Pi] C[1]) <= x < 2 \[Pi] C[1] || \[Pi] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] < x <= 1/6 (7 \[Pi] + 12 \[Pi] C[1])) && y == Sin[x]))
```

Plotting the solution from the algebraic solution is then straightforward:

```
Plot[Sin[x] && Abs[Sin[x]] <= 1/2, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you meant `Plot[ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], Abs[Sin[x]] <= 1/2], {x, 0, 2 π}]`.

Comment: The notation I used worked for me in version 10.2. It produced a similar graph to ubpdqn's answer. I'll include it.

Comment: @Ian Miller:   I find your answer made by hand with help of Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder why `ContourPlot` fails, notice that your two functions touch each other on discrete lines but never cross.

```
Plot3D[{1/2 - Abs[y], 
  Sqrt[(1/2 - Abs[y])^2 + (y - Sin[x])^2]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

`ContourPlot` looks for the difference in the functions to change signs, which it never does.

Knowing this you can get an approximation by plotting a countour line at some small epsilon near zero:

```
 ContourPlot[
 1/2 - Abs[y] - Sqrt[(1/2 - Abs[y])^2 + (y - Sin[x])^2], {x, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 200, Contours -> {-0.0001}, 
 ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

In general an answer to your question is as simple as described in the documentation page:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

As for question, are you sure your equation even has a solution?
If it has, then you should be able to find the roots using `NSolve[]` or `Solve[]`.

Now, none of the above works for your equation, so I assume, you have to first figure out if it's solvable and only then try to plot the values.

Comment: The plot under consideration is not empty. For example, $(0,0)$ and $(-\frac {\pi} 6, -\frac {1} 2)$ belong to the one. @SuTron