# ContourPlot lines just stop abruptly

Tags: plotting

I'm looking for solutions of the equation $1/\omega + \tan(k/\omega)=0$, and for some reason `ContourPlot` is missing a bunch of roots.

```
ContourPlot[1/ω + Tan[k/ω] == 0, {k, 0, 10}, {ω, 0, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 10, FrameLabel -> {"k", "ω"}]
```

[image: ContourPlot with abrupt line ends]

Each of the branches should continue down towards $\omega=0$.
Increasing `PlotPoints` makes no difference.

`NSolve` works fine at a set value of $\omega$:

```
k /. NSolve[{(1/ω + Tan[k/ω]) /. ω -> 0.2, 0 <= k <= 10}, k]
(* {0.353638, 0.981957, 1.61028, 2.23859, 2.86691, 3.49523, 4.12355, 4.75187, 5.38019, 
   6.00851, 6.63682, 7.26514, 7.89346, 8.52178, 9.1501, 9.77842} *)
```

Putting these points on you can see that there are roots missing:

[image]

I'm able to manually make a table and build the plot myself, but just want to know why `ContourPlot` fails so badly here.

Comment: Try plotting the surface corresponding to `1/ω + Tan[k/ω]`, and then mull over the fact that [`ContourPlot[]` relies on the intermediate value theorem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23363) to plot a curve. One obvious workaround is to desingularize: `ContourPlot[Cos[k/ω] + ω Sin[k/ω] == 0, {k, 0, 10}, {ω, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @J.M., Thanks, I didn't know that it used the IVT, although I'm surprised that it doesn't try and follow along the lines once it has found some solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) instead to find solutions to your equation. For example:

```
eqn[k_] = 1/ω[k]+Tan[k/ω[k]] == 0;
ω1 = ω[1] /. NSolve[eqn[1] && 0<ω[1]<1, ω[1]]
```

> {0.00363778, 0.00416084, 0.00464676, 0.00534959, 0.00544103, 0.00606282, \
>   0.00618054, 0.00670096, 0.00699548, 0.00766967, 0.00785902, 0.00805795, \
>   0.00826722, 0.00848765, 0.00872016, 0.00896575, 0.00922559, 0.00950093, \
>   0.00979321, 0.010104, 0.0104353, 0.0107889, 0.0111674, 0.0115734, 0.01201, \
>   0.0124808, 0.01299, 0.0135426, 0.0141443, 0.0148019, 0.0155236, 0.0163192, \
>   0.0172008, 0.0181831, 0.0192843, 0.0205275, 0.0219418, 0.0235654, 0.0254483, \
>   0.027658, 0.0302874, 0.0334688, 0.0373959, 0.0423652, 0.048854, 0.0576822, \
>   0.0703857, 0.0902076, 0.125334, 0.203534, 0.492912}

With an equation and initial values, we can use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn'[k], ω[1]==ω1}, ω, {k,0,10}];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[sol[k], {k,0,10}]
```

[image]