# Why does piecewise plot have a discontinuity when the function, first and second derivatives are equal?

Tags: plotting, piecewise

There were some related questions to this one, but in this case we have the function value, the first derivative and the second derivative all equal (that was actually the problem I was solving).

We have:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{3 x^2 - 3 x + 1, x >= 1}, {x^3, x < 1}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.5}]
```

The answer in those other questions was to use "Exclusions -> None" and it can be used here, but why is this happening since we are good in all derivative information?

**Update**

Some examples of the related questions are:

- [Why does Plot leave gaps in the graph of a continuous function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19877/why-does-plot-leave-gaps-in-the-graph-of-a-continuous-function?rq=1)
- [Plot showing discontinuity where it shouldn't](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13657/plot-showing-discontinuity-where-it-shouldnt)
- [Mathematica plots a discontinuity in piecewise function that does not exist](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24400/mathematica-plots-a-discontinuity-in-piecewise-function-that-does-not-exist?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not sure that I should be saying this, especially since you are such an experienced user, but I think it would help if you provided the link to the other questions that you were mentioning.

Comment: I have added three examples. Regards

Comment: I think Mma will simply put an exclusion at predefined positions for various function types.  E.g. for any `HeavisideTheta` it puts an exclusion to where the argument is zero; for any `Piecewise` function it puts an exclusion inbetween the pieces.  It won't perform additional analysis to figure out that the function is in fact continuous in your case, it just does what it would do for all `Piecewise` functions.  Not very surprising IMO.  Note that the discontinuity detection is not numerical, it's symbolic.

Comment: @Szabolcs `f[x_] := Piecewise[{{3 x^3 - 3 x + 1, x >= 1}, {x^3, x < 1}}] + 3/10`

Comment: Also related: [(35067)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35067/121)

Comment: @belisarius The exclusion is there. You can't see it because accidentally Plot samples points so close to the exclusion that the gap will be practically invisible.  But it's still there and you can make it visible by setting e.g. `ExclusionStyle -> Red`.  Similarly, you can hide the gap in the OP's example by setting a high value to `PlotPoints`, but this doesn't mean that the gap won't exist: it'll just be tiny.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok. I deleted my answer because I wasn't able to see it. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Mathematica* even leaves a gap when the expressions in `Piecewise` are equal, as long as *Mathematica* doesn't see the equality. Very simple example

```
test[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x >= 1}, {Sqrt[x^2], x < 1}}]
Plot[test[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

When you replace `Sqrt[x^2]` by `x`, no gap.

What you have to understand is that the cracks are *features* when you use `Piecewise` because usually a piecewise function has jumps or discontinuities. *Mathematica* really just splits the plot, when it sees `Piecewise` and cannot determine a simple equality between the expressions.

This is a bit unfortunate, because although it is correct most of the time, users will always complain why this doesn't work like they want it.

My short answer: If you don't want cracks, then use `Exclusions->None` or make sure Mathematica doesn't see your `Piecewise`

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{3 x^2 - 3 x + 1, x >= 1}, {x^3, x < 1}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here, the `NumericQ` hinders *Mathematica* to evaluate your expression for non-numeric values and the only chance it has is to put a number in and get a number out :-)

Btw, let's give *Mathematica* something to think about and add *a second* definition for `f` where it sees the `Piecewise`. It doesn't matter what it sees, so screw it:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{"Ding", x < .4}, {"Dong", x < .8}, {"Boing", x < 1.2}}, "Blub"];
```

The important part is that *Mathematica* uses the above definition to see a `Piecewise` and the *gaps* it introduces. For plotting, *Mathematica* has to supply real numbers into `f` and then our very first definition is used. I hope this explains, why the following plot looks as it looks:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [See here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E3NXa.png).

Comment: Sorry, I missed "**add** again a definition"

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  I have made it more clear in the answer what happens and that the first definition of `f` is still required.

Comment: Since I voted for this answer a year ago I wonder if I understood this then.  The declining years...