# Simple Region plot with "or" condition (||) does not connect the or parts "smoothly"?

Tags: plotting, regions

Suppose I want to look at the region defined by the conditions

\begin{align}x\leq y && x<2\\\text{OR}\quad  x\geq y&& x\geq2 \end{align}

I plot this using the command

```
RegionPlot[x <= y  && x < 2 || x >= y && x >= 2, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

which gives the image below.

> Why does this image look the way it does at x=2,y=2, and how can I fix it?

More specifically, I think the regions should only intersect at a point, and should form like a "tilted X". But where the lines cross there is some "width"?

[image: Region plot with OR]

Comment: use the options `PlotPoints`  or `MaxRecursion` or both , e.g., `PlotPoints -> 100]`, and/or `MaxRecursion -> 7`?

Comment: @kglr that indeed fixes it (plotpoints does. Didn't check max recursion). Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Specific initial sample points for 3D plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/specific-initial-sample-points-for-3d-plots) for some discussion of following form of `PlotPoints`. Basically throw a point into the offending area and increase `MaxRecursion` (default value is `2`), if needed.  If you follow the linked Q&A, you'll realize this approach has a good chance to succeed and a still significant chance that it will fail.  It succeeds here if we raise `MaxRecursion` to `3`:

```
RegionPlot[x <= y && x < 2 || x >= y && x >= 2, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> {Automatic, {{2.001, 2.01}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) I never knew of this extended syntax for `PlotPoints`!

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the default discretization method gives the desired singular vertex:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x <= y && x < 2 || x >= y && x >= 2, {{x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}}];
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

We can verify this by highlighting the vertices:

```
HighlightMesh[mesh, Style[0, Red]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment, I can fix it by specifying

```
PlotPoints ->100
```

and/or

```
MaxRecursion-> 7
```

I guess I just didn't/don't understand how the command worked. I looked at the [details of the command](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) and I believe the follows two comments are helpful

- RegionPlot initially evaluates pred at a grid of equally spaced sample points specified by PlotPoints. Then it uses an adaptive algorithm to subdivide at most MaxRecursion times, attempting to find the boundaries of all regions in which pred is True.
- You should realize that since it uses only a finite number of sample points, it is possible for RegionPlot to miss regions in which pred is True. To check your results, you should try increasing the settings for PlotPoints and MaxRecursion.