# Precision problem in DensityPlots

Tags: plotting, machine-precision

I need to  perform a DensityPlot, but the figure is partially  displayed. The codes and figure are shown below.

```
    d = 10^-8; 
    z[x_, y_] := Exp[-((1/x + 1/y - 1/400)/d)^2];
    DensityPlot[z[x, y], {x, 780, 820}, {y, 780, 820}, PlotPoints -> 100,  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &)]
```

[image]

**The portions on the  up-left corner and down-right corner are not displayed.**
I think the reason is that the  system's  precision is not high enough.  The correct figure should be like this：

[image]

Is there any method to overcome this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: While this answer shows a good but arcane use of an option, my other answer shows a better use of the arcane internal structure of graphics to transform this problem from one which `DensityPlot` was not designed to handle into one which it was. IMHO. In other cases, if unable to solve for the transformation, then this approach may be the best option.*

---

From [Specific initial sample points for 3D plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/specific-initial-sample-points-for-3d-plots) and transforming density with `Log`:

```
d = 10^-8;
z[x_, y_] := Exp[-((1/x + 1/y - 1/400)/d)^2];
DensityPlot[Log[2^-1000 + z[x, y]],
 {x, 780, 820}, {y, 780, 820},
 PlotPoints -> {
   45,
   Table[{x, y /. First@Solve[(1/x + 1/y - 1/400) == 0]},
    {x, Subdivide[720, 820, 2 + 3 44][[2 ;; ;; 3]]}]},
 MaxRecursion -> 8, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &), 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
```

[image]

The trouble is that `d` is so small, that the fall-off from the ridge to underflow is probably less than a pixel in width.  Even with sample points on the ridge, some of the ridge is missed (if you play with, say, `PlotPoints`, the sample points, transforming with `Log`, or `WorkingPrecision`). I couldn't hit on settings that gave a complete ridge line without the `Log` transformation.  One can hide the log transformation with `ScalingFunctions`:

```
d = 10^-8;
z[x_, y_] := Exp[-((1/x + 1/y - 1/400)/d)^2];
DensityPlot[$MinMachineNumber + z[x, y],
 {x, 780, 820}, {y, 780, 820},
 PlotPoints -> {
   45,
   Table[{x, y /. First@Solve[(1/x + 1/y - 1/400) == 0]},
    {x, Subdivide[720, 820, 2 + 3 44][[2 ;; ;; 3]]}]},
 MaxRecursion -> 6, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &), 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision,
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It is very helpful. But this method doesnot work when d = 10^-13; Is it possible to solve this problem? @ Michael E2

Comment: I met the problem of "SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]" when I use d = 10^-13

Comment: @user14634 It's a poorly scaled problem to begin with. My first idea was to plot the curve `(1/x + 1/y - 1/400) == 0`, which is in effect what you're doing even in the original problem. My second was to rescale the problem, if possible, or to make a log plot of `z`. But then the above (after several trials) worked. Now `d = 10^-13` makes it harder. For instance, ``z[790.`16, 790.`16]`` cannot be computed. So all I can suggest is a manual log plot. `DensityPlot[Evaluate@ComplexExpand@Log@z[x, y], {x, 780, 820}, {y, 780, 820}]` and explain in the text of your paper if necessary.

Comment: It's rare to find a problem modeling real world phenomena that cannot be done in standard double-precision floating point numbers. I really can't recall ever running into one that can't be done in Mathematica's arbitrary precision numbers, which can be as small as $10^{-10^{15}}$. (Of course, there are no limits on purely mathematical problem. But maybe you can break it down somehow. Scaling `d` by `k` is the same as raising `z` to the power `k^2`. So an explanation for `d = 1` easily translates to an explanation for `d = 10^-8` and `d = 10^-13`.)

Comment: In my case, I need to calculate DensityPlot[z[x, y], {x, 799, 801}, {y, 799, 801}] for d = 10^-13. This is a real-world problem I encountered in my study of physics.

Comment: I have tried DensityPlot[
 Evaluate@ComplexExpand@Log@z[x, y], {x, 799, 801}, {y, 799, 801}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic], but the figure is the same for d=10^-13 and d=10^-23. Is it strange?@Michael E2

Comment: With bounds like `799, 801`, I figured it was from physical science. You might want to take a minute and consider the formula for $z$. It has the form $z=\exp(u/d^2)=\exp(u)^{1/d^2}$, where $u=u(x,y)$. So $\log z=\log\exp(u/d^2)=u/d^2$. So the plot of $\log z$ has the shape for any $d$, only scaled by $1/d^2$. Add `PlotLegends -> Automatic` to `DensityPlot[]` and it will show the z scale to the side of the graphics. You might ask someone in your field about how to represent $z$.

Answer (score 2):

*I thought this should be a different answer for two reasons: (1) This is a different approach, which shouldn't be buried in another answer and should be evaluated as an alternative on its own merits. (2) The other answer is over a week old and has been evaluated by the community, and it didn't feel right adding something unrelated to it. [Maybe a third reason: I'm rather happy with the result. I hope the OP is, too. :) ]*

---

We can transform the coordinates so the the region of interest is parallel to a coordinate axis. At first I thought this would be hopeless because the exponential function decreases so rapidly. But  it works well with plotting $\log z$.  Adding a fixed color function, fixed by the smallest $d$, which gives the greatest dynamic range, allows comparison of plots for different values of $d$.  Finally, $\log z$ varies over 37 orders of magnitude for $d=10^{23}$, a log-scale color function and bar legend help show the variation.

*The coordinate transformation*

We will transform from $(x,y)$ to $(u,w)$, create the plot, and transform back to $(x,y)$. The following shows what the transformation looks like.

```
Solve[{u == 1/x + 1/y - 1/400, w == 1/x - 1/y}, {x, y}]
(*
{{x -> 800/(1 + 400 u + 400 w), y -> 800/(1 + 400 u - 400 w)}}
*)

Solve[{u == 1/x + 1/y - 1/400, w == 1/x - 1/y}, {u, w}]
% /. {{x -> 780, y -> 780}, {x -> 780, y -> 820}, {x -> 820, 
   y -> 780}, {x -> 820, y -> 820}}
(*
{{u -> -(1/400) + 1/x + 1/y, w -> (-x + y)/(x y)}}

{{{u -> 1/15600, w -> 0}},           (* bounds on {u, w} *)
 {{u -> 1/639600,  w -> 1/15990}},
 {{u -> 1/639600, w -> -(1/15990)}},
 {{u -> -(1/16400), w -> 0}}}
*)

ParametricPlot[{800/(1 + 400 u + 400 w), 800/(1 + 400 u - 400 w)},
 {u, -(1/15600), 1/15600}, {w, -(1/15990), 1/15990}, 
 FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

*Creating the plots*

As mentioned above, the color scheme is proportion to $\log\log z$. Equal increments of $\log |\log z|$ since $0<z\le1$ correspond to equal changes in the argument to the color function.
Actually, equal increments in $\log(1+|\log z|)$ are used so that a color is defined for $z=1$.
We use this to create a bar legend to be used uniformly for all values of $d$. To ensure that the bar legend comprises the range of $z$, construct it using the smallest value of $d$ to be considered.
Some adjustment of the scale (ticks) would be needed for different values of $d$.

```
(* color function, legend, and transformation *)
d = 10^-23;
z[x_, y_] := Exp[-((1/x + 1/y - 1/400)/d)^2];
cfs[z_] := 1 - Log10[1 - z]/38;
leg = BarLegend[{Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, Sow[1 - Log10[1 - #]/38]] &,
    Table[N@ComplexExpand@Log@z[x, y],
      {x, 780, 820}, {y, 780, 820}] // MinMax},
   Table[-10.^(5 k), {k, 7}], LegendLabel -> HoldForm[Log[z]]];
uw2yx = Function @@ {{u, w}, {x, y} /. 
     First@Solve[{u == 1/x + 1/y - 1/400, w == 1/x - 1/y}, {x, y}]};

(* the plots *)
GraphicsRow[
 Table[
  Show[
   DensityPlot[
     Evaluate[
      ComplexExpand@Log@z[x, y] /. {x -> 800/(1 + 400 u + 400 w), 
        y -> 800/(1 + 400 u - 400 w)}],
     {u, -(1/15600) (1 + 4/100), 
      1/15600 (1 + 4/100)}, {w, -(1/15990) (1 + 4/100), 
      1/15990 (1 + 4/100)},
     MaxRecursion -> 6,
     PlotRange -> All,
     ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, cfs[#]] &),
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     WorkingPrecision -> 24,
     PlotLegends -> leg, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Row[{HoldForm[d], " = ", 
        HoldForm[10]^
         Log10[d]}]] /. {pp_List?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &) /; 
       MatchQ[Dimensions[pp], {_, 2}] :> 
      Transpose[uw2yx @@ Transpose@pp]},
   PlotRange -> {{780, 820}, {780, 820}},
   ImageSize -> 300],
  {d, {10^-8, 10^-13, 10^-23}}],
 ImageSize -> 1300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the line of interest corresponds to $u=0$, the center of the plot domain for `u`.  The default `PlotPoints` is ***odd*** and so the center is automatically included in the sampling.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I still need more time to learn this code.