# Plotting 3D complex numbers with colours

Tags: plotting, color, complex

I am new to Mathematica and am taking a course in Complex Analysis. I was wondering how to do the following: Plot in 3D (using Plot3D) the real part of f(x+I*y) and then colouring the corresponding 3D plot using some color scheme so that I can see the Imaginary part of f(x+I*y) by looking at the color. Sorry if this question is very elementary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use the `ColorFunction` option of `Plot3D`. For instance: `Plot3D[Re[f[x + I y]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Im[f[x + I y]]]]`

Comment: Take a look at this previous answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4273/484

Comment: FYI, I think it's more common to plot the magnitude of $|f|$ along the $z$-axis, and use $\arg(f)$ to determine the color.  The color wheel maps nicely onto the $[0, 2\pi)$ range of the $\arg$ function.

Comment: I know but for my purposes I would prefer to have it this way.

Comment: If you want a high-quality output of your colored surface, you should consider reading this QA: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19110/187

Answer (score 3):

```
f[x_] = x^3;
```

The `min` and `max` of the `Im` values are

**EDIT:** Corrected error in calculating `{min, max}`

```
{min, max} = #[{ComplexExpand@Im[f[x + I*y]], -3 <= x <= 3, -3 <= y <= 3}, {x,
      y}] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}

(* {-54, 54} *)

Legended[
 Plot3D[Re[f[x + I*y]],
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
     {"x", "y", "Re[f[x+I*y]]"}),
  ColorFunction -> (
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"]
      [(Im[f[#1 + I*#2]] - min)/(max - min)] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {min, max}},
  LegendLabel -> "Im[f[x+I*y]]"]]
```

[image]

For comparison purposes to verify accuracy of colors

```
Plot3D[Im[f[x + I*y]],
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"x", "y", "Im[f[x+I*y]]"})]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. Turned out to be less elementary than I thought.