# How to plot "Re-Im" 3d plot with `ComplexPlot3D` (`MeshFunctions -> {Re[#2] &, Im[#2] &}` should work, but doesn't)

Tags: plotting, complex

By default the

```
f[z_] = ((z^2 - 1)*((z - 2 - I)^2)) / (z^2 + 2 + 2*I) 
ComplexPlot3D[f[z], {z, 10}]
```

will output `AbsArg 3d plot` (because by default the `MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#2] &, Arg[#2] &}`)

But I want `ReIm 3d plot` like here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125633/86077

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/spLJ7.png]

But there should be easier way

But when I try `MeshFunctions -> {Re[#2] &, Im[#2] &}` it doesnt work, it still shows `AbsArg` plot

1. WHY?
2. How `MeshFunctions` work? how the output is used?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you  want to plot ? `Abs@f[z]` or `ReIm@f[z]`? `ComplexPlot3D` only plot `Abs@f[z]`.

Comment: If `f` is a function from `x + y i` to `re + im i` them i want `x y` as bottom axis , `re` as `vertical` axis and `im` as temperature

Comment: ComplexPlot3D  plots abs as vertical axis and arg as temperature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[z_] = ((z^2 - 1)*((z - 2 - I)^2))/(z^2 + 2 + 2*I);
Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
 Plot3D[Re@f[z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Im@f[z]]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
```

[image]

We can add `Mesh` and the same time.

```
f[z_] = ((z^2 - 1)*((z - 2 - I)^2))/(z^2 + 2 + 2*I);
Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
 Plot3D[Re@f[z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Im@f[z]]], 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, Im@f[z]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: But the idea of this question is how to do this with `ComplexPlot3D`?

Comment: @srghma It is impossible to do this by  `ComplexPlot3D` since `ComplexPlot3D` can only plot `Abs@f[z]`.

Comment: Ah, ok, also now i understand (after seeing second example) what `MeshFunctions` are doing